# Excel formula to split text using multiple delimiters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split, excel-2010, formula

I have data string which has characters as , / and (). I need an excel formula that can split text between these three characters and paste in consecutive column. I found formula that can split text using any one delimiter but I want for multiple delimiters at a time. Consider string is in A2 and have to be split and pasted in consecutive rows.

Comment: Can you use text to columns? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to use VBA macros.

Comment: Please show sample data with expected results.